# Concat and sort n pre-sorted arrays most efficiently

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 3 arrays each having elements that are a subclass of Sortable, which has a getter with "index", a positive Number that represents its order in the sort.

2 of the arrays are sorted ascending while the third is unsorted. The final array must be sorted ascending too.

If you want the specifics, the first array are buildings in an isometric grid, the second is made of props, such as trees. The third one (unsorted) is full of "actors" that move around and change their index quite often.

I have contemplated keeping all the things in the same array and just sort that array, but its basically just as sluggish.

I have tried array's native sort and sortOn but it is still slow( about 10 ms for 2 concats and a sort on the final array ). It really too much, I'd like it halved at least, but it would be better a more elegant solution (I am sure mine sucks).

I can't use Vectors because I can't combine the 3 subclasses in a Vector.. I know it should work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

First, `Vector.<Sortable>` will do for subclasses too. Second, why don't you keep buildings and trees in one array, actors in another, then sort in two phases - first actors, then merge.

Comment: Subclasses does not work, I have tried. The props array contains many particles (for smoke & such) and is recreated in a sorted state. the actor array contains the same nr of elements but their index changes. the buildings don't change in number or index (that often, they do change from user interaction).

Comment: Weird, I have just tried with `Vector.<Sprite>` and added different instances of classes that extend Sprite. Perhaps you need to try harder, or revise your class structure to verify that all of your classes are subclasses of `Sortable` or, in case of an interface, all classes have `implements Sortable` in declaration.